# Typescript: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type

Tags: typescript

In the following code, TypeScript seems to flippantly decide when a type is indexable by a string:

```
type Model = { [k: string]: any };

export class MyClass<TModel extends Model> {

    get(target: TModel, key: string) {
        return target[key];  //passes
    }

    set(target: TModel, key: string, value: any) {
        target[key] = value; //ts(2536) Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'TModel'
    } 

}
```

TypeScript version: 4.7.2.

I've been bumping into this issue a lot lately and I'm wondering if anyone knows why.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the exact explanation of why that doesn't work -- but I can fix the problem for you:

Type your "key" arguments as `keyof TModel` rather than string. E.g.:

```
set(target: TModel, key: keyof TModel, value: any) {
```

Perhaps because TModel *extends* Model, the checker thinks there could be a non-string prop key that would be referenced by a string.

Another solution might be to simply remove the generic parameter and type the `target` arguments as `Model`. You're not really using that generic type anyway. Anything that extends Model will still be accepted as those first arguments.

This code compiles fine with either approach:

```
const sym = Symbol("whatevs");
const my = new MyClass();
const model = { some: "thing", [sym]: "what?" };
my.set(model, "some", "other thing");
```

Comment: It works to fix that single case, but the key needs to be re-usable with different objects.  Sometimes their type isn't defined so this becomes complicated.  It seems like the ideal would be to define the type as indexable by string.

Comment: You might not need the generic parameter in this case -- just added to my answer.

Comment: Either approach i've suggested here should work in all cases.